# Adding to an Array List

Tags: java, methods, arraylist

When I attempt to add to my array list (stringer), this error occurs:

```
error: no suitable method found for add(Fish)
      stringer.add(f);
```

In this code:

```
public class Habitat {

ArrayList<String> stringer = new ArrayList<String>();
int[] fishArr;
public int maxCount=25; 
public int minCount=9; 
public int maxWeight=10; 
public int minWeight=1; 
public int catchProbability=30; //0.3 

public int[] stockUp(){
  int numofF = minCount + (int)(Math.random() * ((maxCount - minCount) + 1));
  for(int i = 0; i<numofF; i++){
     fishArr[i] = minWeight + (int)(Math.random() * ((maxWeight - minWeight) + 1));
  }
  return fishArr;
}


public Habitat(){
  int[] hab;
}

public void addFish(Fish f) {
  stringer.add(f);
}

public void removeFish(Fish f){
  stringer.remove(f);
}

public void printFish(){
  System.out.println(stringer);
}
}
```

The remove works just fine, so I don't understand why the add doesn't work. I would like the problem explained, so I don't make the same mistake again.

Comment: `ArrayList<String>`........................

Answer (score 4):

You've declared the `List` so that it is expecting `String` values only, but you are trying to add `Fish` object to it...

This is a violation of the contract you made with `ArrayList`

Try using `ArrayList<Fish> stringer = new ArrayList<Fish>();` instead

Take a look at [Generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/) for more details

Comment: As op mention remove work fine.  He may doing something wrong. Is it so?

Comment: @NFE [`List#remove`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#remove(java.lang.Object)) accepts an `Object` parameter and therefore isn't part of the generics contract.  The code won't "work", as it won't compile

Answer (score 0):

stringer is ArrayList of String you cannot add Objects of type Fish to it.